# How to set minHeight of View programmatically?

Tags: android, android-view

There is a xml attribute: `android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"`.
To set it programmatically, I guess I need to use `textView.setMinHeight();` method, but which argument should I put in the method?

**Edit**. My question is not about which method should I use, but how to transform `"?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` attribute into an integer value in the method `textView.setMinHeight()`. Sorry if I incorrectly expressed.

Comment: `I guess`.  Why?  Why not read the documentation?

Comment: Do you use IDE? When you will write view.setMin - it would say to you all methods stats with this letters.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed textView's method `setMinHeight` with the method `setMinimumHeight`. It's just a typo.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `View.setMinimumHeight()`

More info at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMinimumHeight(int)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [doc link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMinimumHeight(int)). It receives an `int` which is the height of the item in pixels, not in dps.
As stated in the documentation:

> minWidth    The minimum width the view will try to be.

Answer (score -2):

This should work for you:

```
TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight, value, true);
float itemHeight = value.getDimension(getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```